# Comments not showing up when set to open and assigned a region in manage display in drupal 7

Tags: 7, theming, entities, comments

I just set my comments for my content type to "open" and assigned the comment field to show up in the full content manage display. But it doesnt show up when viewing in my full display node. I tried changing the theme and it still doesnt show up. How can I debug something like this?

Comment: Make sure your theme's [node.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.tpl.php/7.x) has `print render($content['comments']);`

Comment: doesn't look like my node.tpl.php is loading. maybe because im using display suite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that comments was "CLOSED" for the nodes I already created as the default setting initially was set as "CLOSED". Even thought I set the comment settings to OPEN on the content type, this doesn't affect previously created work.

Solution was to bulk update all the nodes types to open comments with the following sql:

```
UPDATE node SET comment = 0 WHERE type LIKE "MY_NODE_TYPE_HERE";
```